# Difference between convention and configurational frameworks

Tags: php, frameworks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Benefits of the “Convention over Configuration” paradigm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347015/benefits-of-the-convention-over-configuration-paradigm)

What is the difference between convention and configurational frameworks ? Please list some examples in both cases especially for PHP. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Gordon thanks for link need PHP frameworks which falls into these categories. Thanks

Comment: Asking for frameworks is not a good fit for StackOverflow. If user A supplies one and user B supplies one, too, how would decide which answer to accept? It's up to you to research those.